# Span DIV 100% width of web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a 'Services' link on my web page which that when clicked displays a sub menu. I would like to span this sub menu 100% width of my page.

Is this possible & how do I change my code to allow this?

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/19y4qnkx/

I am using Bootstrap.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left ">
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Services  </a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><div class="yamm-content"> <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left"> <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li> <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li> <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li> <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li> </ul></div>
            </li>
</ul>

    </li>

</ul>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give 100% width to the dropdown menu and all of it's parents. But the Services link will also have the full with.

```
.navbar-nav
{
    width: 100%;
}

.dropdown{
 width: 100%
}

.dropdown-menu{
 width: 100%
}
```

I updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/19y4qnkx/4/

Edit: Just saw that this is breaking the style on smaller screens. Here`s a updated fiddle with media query http://jsfiddle.net/19y4qnkx/6/

Comment: Is it possible 'Services' will remain at its existing width?

Comment: Yes, if you give the link a "display: inline-block". http://jsfiddle.net/19y4qnkx/10/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use vw unit in your css for your ".dropdown-menu" like this :

```
.dropdown-menu{
  min-width: 100vw;
}
```

I let you check here for compatibility here http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know did I get it right, or even come close to it because it's very tricky to change Bootstrap css styles that are being applied. However, I changed the DIV:  `<div class="yamm-content">` to use css class `'test'` as well in following fasthion: `<div class="yamm-content test">`

Below is the css class test:

```
.test {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/19y4qnkx/9/)

Now when you expand the dropdown menu the background of the sub menu appears in yellow color. The Services menu text has red border around it, so there is still fine tuning to do. Well, like it said it's tricky to change afterwards Bootstrap CSS styles. I don't know if this could be solved by doing your own Bootstrap [customization](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/).